# How to type action types correctly in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to type `action names` but something I'm doing wrong.

It throws an error when I try to use it on `reducer` function when trying to call `updateProduct` function, even though I typed action names correctly.

```
Property 'update' does not exist on type 'ActionDelete'.
```

Here is the way I tried to implement it.
I've created an `enum` for `action names` and used them according to action type and type `Action` is an alias which is either `ActionUpdate` or `ActionDelete`.

```
enum ActionTypes {
    update = 'update',
    delete = 'delete'
}

interface ActionUpdate {
    type: ActionTypes.update;
    update: string;
}

interface ActionDelete {
    type: ActionTypes.delete;
    delete: string;
}

type Action =
    | ActionUpdate
    | ActionDelete
```

I've created an `interface for a call signature with positional arguments`

```
 interface ActionProps {
    (
        product: Product,
        value: Value,
        cart: Cart,
        action?: Action
    ): void;
}
```

And here is the rest of usage of Action in reducer function.
Reducer function

```
 const Reducer = (
    product: Product,
    value:Value,
    cart: Cart,
    action: Action,
) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case 'update':
            updateProduct( product, value, cart);
            break;
        default: {
            throw new Error('Unknown type');
        }
    }
};
```

And as an example here is `updateProduct` functon for `update`

```
const updateProduct: ActionProps = ( product, value, cart, action) => {
    cart.name = action.update;  // Error throws here on "action.update"
};
```

Here is a [link for testing](https://playcode.io/1332451)

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Your `updateProduct` reducer function looks like it mutates state - is that intentional? You are aware that in Redux/React your reducers _must never_ mutate state?

Comment: @Dai thanks for answer. 
You can ignore functionality inside the "updateProduct".

Comment: I can't ignore the functionality in `updateProduct` because that's exactly where the TSC error is coming from...

Comment: If you comment the line `//cart.name = action.update; `  and check just  `console.log(action.update)` will throw same error

Comment: Your `updateProduct` function is typed as `ActionProps` which means it's declared as accepting an `ActionDelete` _or_ an `ActionUpdate` object. Change `updateProduct`'s type if it should only accept an `ActionUpdate` object.

Comment: @Dai Change `updateProduct's` type to what?

Comment: You can make your `ActionProps` interface generic like this: https://tsplay.dev/WP1EJw

Comment: @vr. great that solves my Problem, can you post your answer so that I can make as a correct answer?

Comment: @vr. one more question, please, implementing it on my base code I get this error `Type 'ActionProps' is not generic.ts`.  
Can you, please, explain, why?

Comment: I don't think you put the generic in the right place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your `ActionProps` interface generic, defaulting to `Action`. This way, you can optionally provide a specific action if you need to.

```
interface ActionProps<A extends Action = Action> {
    (product: Product, value: Value, cart: Cart, action?: A): void;
}
```

Then in your definition of `updateProduct`, pass the right action type:

```
const updateProduct: ActionProps<ActionUpdate> = (product, value, cart, action) => {
    if (!action) return;

    cart.name = action.update; // okay
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAggxgFwJYHsQBUCeAHYBnKAbwCgoyoxsATAQwWCgF4oAiS2+lgGlPKuAA2wek1b8hnHgF9ixJCHoAnAGY04DeMjQBVanQYlyUBDmAAuWIlQZTeAHTt9Abl5lH9C3gSL5AcxcycgrAKmoaVmgAIoLCBq7Gphaa1li49uKxLkYZHlBePiD+xIEmuJZaIKLJOnoiAD7l1tESwC5BSqrqjWgACooo2HgAPDBQwAAe9CBUBNWVzHMAfETxABTY-VRgiBZ9KFuIXFAAbjQCYOZQAGpnF0dwNIoIFgDCjwhHahUA-EkAlBZjigkFQArI4GgvFAAErAA4hUTrTbbZ5QPYHD4nW6XG7nYD3d6vd6fCIgJKkv5MZaGch4ADuSAQcAAFlBVl9rHZSsBKTSjGQHngGGxasAWGZ4vzyO5gOiUUj9iijqc8QSnn8slL+QAjRTAGgAa01Uv4qjAAlRfK1ZAQzP6dKgIGADoAoop+opVixtCADSAUHTKtyWBrJeQZEYZFI2hCQFCZXKdt0QHtBiNSboOMBlswFRjldi1ZiOWhKYxqfEkMo2QBCEsgSl6hBgRQgNpGB5POwgGgQBjMesOUVOKAAelHUBQBpomGKbXkHTCaORiCIjt7l3yfigMgXIU6DFxFzXPb7nm8293wVCXTeTxPG-PBV8O6AA)

---

You could just use a type alias instead of an interface:

```
type ActionProps<A extends Action = Action> = (product: Product, value: Value, cart: Cart, action?: A) => void;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your `ActionProps` interface has an optional parameter `action?: Action` where `Action` can be either `ActionDelete` or `ActionUpdate` - in your code, you're assuming that `ActionProps` will only ever return an `ActionUpdate` type and therefore you don't handle the case where the action could be of `ActionDelete` type

The easiest option would be to set the `action` inside of `ActionProps` to `ActionUpdate` i.e. `action?: ActionUpdate` (assuming that you won't return an `ActionDelete` action in this scenario)

Alternatively, it would be best if you restructured your types to be more explicit as to what you're expecting so you can avoid these types of errors

Comment: Hi @HazAnwar can you, please, provide an example, what you described above?

Comment: @FD3 https://redux.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript - specifically the part about typed reducers

Comment: i.e. remove the `Action` type you have created and use either `ActionUpdate` or `ActionDelete` directly, which solves your issue and makes your types more explicit